# EJB 3.1 remote access + Jboss 7.3 +JPA

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, sqldatasource

I have created a EJB 3.1 application which uses remoting EJB project jar is deployed on  Jboss application and Web project Client war is deployed on Tomcat  server both the servers are running on different machine and used JPA for database operation in EJB project which is lookup from Web Project deployed on tomcat. 
  Can somebody suggest me how i can get reference of data source in remote client application and run a select query on that reference.
Below link i have used for reference.
URL: https://tutorialsjoint.com/ejb-stateless-implementation-using-remote-jndi-lookup/

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you need to access the database you must create a datasource in tomcat

Comment: Hi Simon Martinelli , I have created database over jboss server and that's currently runing over different machine. I need reference of that data source by using  remoting concept. Can you suggest is it possible to get and how it can be done. I have newly started working with ejb application.

Comment: That's not possible. You can call remote EJBs that access the database

Comment: I want to reduce database connection count. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Why does your application run on two nodes?

Comment: I am just testing remote ejb features so i have deployed client on tomcat in my machine and jboss on another system .

Comment: That's fine but as you say "remote EJB" not remote datasource.

Comment: Ok. how can we achieve remote datasource here.

Comment: Which JBoss version do you have?

Comment: EJB 3.1 and Jboss 7.3 version.

Comment: Is this EAP 7.3.?

Comment: yes it is jboss-eap-7.3.0

Comment: Then I'm sorry. This is no longer possible. It was possible to give a JNDI name to the datasource that could be access from remote until JBoss EAP 5

Comment: Thanks for your time and response Simon.

Comment: I added my comment as the anwer

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer possible.

It was possible to give a JNDI name to the datasource that could be access from remote until JBoss EAP 5.